# Need formula to count the number of true values for an aggregated attribute based on a larger dataset

Tags: google-sheets

I've created an example spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YmgkZoSvwhb0akYOUQx8atscdv3UVcmieD9-fho4Uxs/edit?usp=sharing). The dataset I'm using is significantly larger, approx 2,000 rows.

The larger dataset has hundreds of rows per `Market` and dozens of rows per `Partner` along with `TRUE/FALSE` values for two parameters (`Called` & `Registered`).

What I want to do is create a smaller table that will track both Called and Registered progress on the market level. I'm fine with this simply being a COUNT function (although ultimately I'd like to turn that into a percent (`TRUE` / `FALSE`= `%`).

Because the real dataset is so large, I can't use a simple `COUNTIF` function - and I also need the formula to be replicable for similar datasets. I tried using a `FILTER` function: `=COUNTIF(FILTER(B10:E,B10:B=B3),D10:D=TRUE)` - to match the `Market` value but that hasn't worked.

I've included markdown text along with a screenshot below. Greatly appreciate the help!

| Market | Called Progress | Registered Progress |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New York |  |  |  |
| California |  |  |  |
| Texas |  |  |  |
| Florida |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
| Market | Partner | Called | Registered |
| New York | John | FALSE | FALSE |
| New York | Mary | FALSE | FALSE |
| New York | Henry | FALSE | FALSE |
| California | Laura | FALSE | FALSE |
| California | Kevin | FALSE | FALSE |
| California | James | FALSE | FALSE |
| Texas | Michael | FALSE | FALSE |
| Texas | Sandra | FALSE | FALSE |
| Texas | Sarah | FALSE | FALSE |
| Florida | Jennifer | FALSE | FALSE |
| Florida | Harry | FALSE | FALSE |
| Florida | David | FALSE | FALSE |

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `query()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( query( 
  if( islogical(B9:E), B9:E + 0, B9:E ), 
  "select 
     Col1, 
     sum(Col3) / count(Col3), 
     sum(Col4) / count(Col4) 
   where Col1 is not null 
   group by Col1 
   label 
     sum(Col3) / count(Col3) 'Called Progress', 
     sum(Col4) / count(Col4) 'Registered Progress' 
   format 
     sum(Col3) / count(Col3) '0%', 
     sum(Col4) / count(Col4) '0%' ", 
  1 
) )
```

This gives a table like this:

| Market | Called Progress | Registered Progress |
| --- | --- | --- |
| California | 100% | 67% |
| Florida | 67% | 33% |
| New York | 33% | 33% |
| Texas | 33% | 0% |

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=BYROW(B3:B6, LAMBDA(x, SUMPRODUCT(B9:B=x, D9:D)))
```

and:

```
=BYROW(B3:B6, LAMBDA(x, SUMPRODUCT(B9:B=x, E9:E)))
```

[image]